# How can I find whether if an element in arr1 is also in arr2 in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, find

For example, I have 2 arrays:

```
arr1 = ["a","e","i","o","u"];
arr2 = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"];
```

I would like to find whether any of the elements in arr2 contain any of the elements that are already available in arr1.

Comment: That's invalid JS code to describe an array: `arr1 = ["a","e","i","o","u"];` Please edit your question to fix the code.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check whether one of the items in `arr2` is included in `arr1`:

```js
arr1 = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
arr2 = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"];

const res = arr2.some(e => arr1.includes(e))
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

Find the array with below filter function

```
let array1 = ["a","e","i","o","u"]; 
let array2 = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"];

const filteredArray = array1.filter(value => array2.includes(value));
```

`filteredArray.length` will give you the answer

Comment: you can use `.some` instead of filter.

Comment: The guy said they wanted to know "whether" any of them are in the other array. It depends on your use case, but yeah it seems like they don't care about the actual values inside the arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
arr1 = ["a","e","i","o","u"]; 
arr2 = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"];

let res = arr1.some(el1 => {
    return arr2.some(el2 => el1 === el2);
});

console.log(res) // true
```